# What does "die Augen aufschlugen" mean?

Tags: translation, verb, meaning-in-context, german-to-english

Native English speaker here, trying to learn more German by reading `Harry Potter und der Stein der Weisen`, and I came across this sentence:

> **Als Mr. und Mrs. Dursley** an dem trüben und grauen Dienstag, an dem unsere  Geschichte beginnt, **die Augen aufschlugen**, war an dem
>   wolkenverhangenen Himmel  draußen kein Vorzeichen der merkwürdigen und
>   geheimnisvollen Dinge zu erkennen, die bald überall im Land geschehen
>   sollten.

I'm thrown off by the phrase "die Augen aufschlugen", although I know by context and from reading the English it means basically, "to wake up, to open one's eyes".

I've done a search of PONS, LEO and dict.cc online dictionaries, and found out that (auf)schlagen typically means something like "to hit, serve, pitch".

I'm wondering if this might be a colloquial/ugs. in German, since the literal meaning of the verb doesn't seem to fit the context very well. Is this an idiomatic phrase in German? What kind of extra meaning does the verb aufschlagen add to the phrase, as opposed to, for example, aufwachen?

Comment: You can also: "ein Buch aufschlagen" (to open a book).

Comment: You didn't look far enough - dict.cc has "Augen aufschlagen" about 75% down.

Comment: If you can read books in German, you can use a German dictionary. [meaning #4](https://www.dwds.de/wb/aufschlagen)

Comment: *Schlag* is one of these words with different meanings over the whole page.

Comment: @Carsten, your condescension isn't appreciated. Your link, however, is. I've never heard of or used DWDS before, so I'll be sure to check there from now on, in addition to the others.

Comment: @tofro, I actually did find that definition on dict.cc. However, the definition there is lacking: "to cast ones eyes up". This isn't a normal phrase in English, unless its archaic, and certainly doesn't mean "to wake up"' it would mean something more like "to look up in the sky".

Comment: You could also give the Duden a try. It is still the most popular German dictionary. Although mainly focused on grammar and spelling, it also lists briefly different meanings of a word. For _aufschlagen_ it distinguishes not less than 13 variants. Yours is #7: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufschlagen#Bedeutung7

Comment: I apologise for my brevity that you took for something else. My fault. And by the way, you can of course ask here if the dictionaries don’t solve your problem, but your questions will be better if your dictionaries are better. Judging by your answer to toro, it seems that we both agree that dict.cc is not a good substitute for a dictionary ;)

Comment: An aside, but if the translation had been from German to English, I wonder if the translator would have chosen to keep "Herr and Frau" rather than anglicising them?

Answer (score 16):

> I'm wondering if this might be a colloquial/ugs. in German

No, on the contrary it is rather a bit elevated and poetic style, particularly when the intended meaning is "to wake up" and not a more general "to open one's eyes".

> What kind of extra meaning does the verb aufschlagen add to the phrase, as opposed to, for example, aufwachen?

I can see two advantages of *Augen aufschlagen* compared to *aufwachen* in this phrase which make it (well, in my opinion at least) the better choice here from a literary point of view:

1. It avoids the stylistic problem of putting three verbs aside ("... Geschichte **beginnt, aufwachten, war** an ..."). The middle one would make a single-word sub-clause, which is not so nice to read.
2. It matches the content that follows, which is about something that the Dursleys could (more exactly: could not) **see**: "war an dem wolkenverhangenen Himmel draußen kein Vorzeichen der merkwürdigen und geheimnisvollen Dinge zu erkennen". So by choosing *Augen aufschlugen* the translator links the Dursleys to the events that are about to happen. He creates the impression  of the Dursleys looking into that cloudy sky.

Comment: Wobei es den Augenaufschlag, wenn auch nicht im hiesigen Kontext, als Flirtsignal gibt.

Answer (score 8):

*Aufschlagen* in the sense of opening originates from books with a clasp where you literally had to hit the book for the clasp to open. From there the use of *aufschlagen* was transferred to other things that can be opened.

Comment: Interesting. Could you link a reference regarding this usage transfer?

Comment: I cannot seem to find a a link about the usage transfer at the moment. I had been told of the connection by a librarian (difficult to link here^^) but I'll keep looking.

Comment: I promise to upvote, if you link to a reliable source! Just ping me as a reminder! - Even though it would be nice to try to actually answer the question, too. ;)

Comment: "Schlag das Buch auf!" will be a commonly found phrase; everyone will understand to open the book, not impact something with it.

Comment: It could be also used for a chest or something as a synonym for ‚aufklappen‘.

Answer (score 2):

It is not used in the colloquial sense, but it has an important use for narration. I would not say it is not only "elevated" or "poetic" as Matthias suggests, it simply indicates a sudden awakening after a unspecified time has passed and/or something unusual and important has happened.

*Plötzlich war da ein Zaun, ein Aufprall, er spürte noch, wie er vom Fahrrad flog...dann wurde es schwarz. Als er die Augen aufschlug, sah er eine hellblau gefärbte Decke und es roch nach Krankenhaus.*

*Die letzte, große Prüfung. Sie entspannte sich noch ein wenig auf der Bank und genoß die Sonne des Mittags auf dem Gesicht. Als sie die Augen aufschlug, sah sie einen dunklen, klaren Himmel...**Hatte sie etwa verschlafen?!***

You never use it in normal talk or as polite suggestion/imperative, e.g. "Er/sie hat die Augen aufgeschlagen/Schlagen Sie bitte die Augen auf". If it **is** used for addressing, it is in the best case sarcastic or teasing, but otherwise **it indicates trouble**, e.g. "Schlag gefälligst die Augen auf, wenn ich mit Dir rede!"

Answer (score 1):

These online dictionaries are incomplete. If you consult an etymological dictionary, e.g. Kluge writes about "schlagen" that while it has the meaning of "to hit" (from middle- and old high german, 8th century) it and its predecessors (old-nordic slagr, old-english slege, old-high-german slag, middle-high-german slac, slag) also **have several special meanings**.

All of these special meanings are only losely connected to the primary meaning and often appear in compound words or with prefixes.
For example "Schlag" (noun) can mean a hit, but it can also mean a type of something, with the link being that it was used to denote a group of trees designated to be cut down together.
For prefixes, "verschlagen" (adj.) means to be tricky, shifty.

"aufschlagen" is simply one of these special meanings. My old hardcover Kluge does not contain its context, and I don't want to post guesswork.

- This source: https://www.dwds.de/wb/aufschlagen shows that even "aufschlagen" has multiple meanings (e.g. it can also mean to fall upon something)
- This source: https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/das-buch-aufschlagen-woher-kommt-dieser-begriff repeats the statement made by Rhabarberbarbara, but also without sources. It might be true or a common misconception

In summary: It is a special meaning of the word, with no ready-to-find reasoning. You will just have to learn it by heart. Even as a native german speaker I cannot give you an easy explanation.

Comment: Also: "Zuschlag","Abschlag" meaning a surcharge or a discount. "zuschlagen", "draufschlagen" can mean adding a surcharge ... or seizing an opportunity (colloq. zuschlagen), or acknowledging a winning bid in an auction (Zuschlag) ...  or throwing the first punch in a fight (zuschlagen), battering an opponent (draufschlagen), impacting something (aufschlagen)....

Comment: @rackandboneman "zuschlagen" in the sense of "seizing an opportunity" veeery probably is a boxing or at least general fighting metaphor. The winning bid of an auction is often announced with a gavel. - Most of your examples are just variations of actually hitting something. - Only "Zuschlag" and "Abschlag" are not immediately obvious as derived from "schlagen" in its literal sense...

Comment: You have a point. Luckily, it is only the table that is hit with a gavel.